# Can I transit UK with a paper Permesso di Soggiorno?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, permesso-di-soggiorno

I have a valid residency in Italy (Permesso di Soggiorno), but it is in paper format.

In this page: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa I see a statement in exemptions such as: a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland

Although I can travel within the Schengen area with it, I don't know if it is "a common format" and therefore valid for transiting UK.

I am a Turkish citizen and I will not leave the airport area during the transit
it

The paper looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This document is **not** valid for visa-free transit - you need a residence permit **card** (that's what a "common-format" permit currently refers to).

So you will need a visa.